# Can consecutive updates to different fields on a row in Cassandra lead to inconsistency?

Tags: cassandra

Assuming you have a table with a field (column) that serves as the primary (partition) key (let say its name is "id") and the rest of the fields columns are "regular" (no clustering) - lets call them "field1", "field2", field3", "field4", etc. The logic that currently exists in the system might generate 2 separate update commands to the same row. For example:

```
UPDATE table SET field1='value1' WHERE id='key';
UPDATE table SET field2='value2' WHERE id='key';
```

These commands run one after the other in quorum.

Seldom, when you retrieve the row (quorum read) from the DB, its as if one of the updates did not happen. Is it possible that the inconsistency is because of this write pattern and can be circumvented by making one update call like this:

```
UPDATE table SET field1='value1',field2='value2' WHERE id='key';
```

This is happening on Cassandra 2.1.17

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is totally possible.

If you need to preserve the orders when making the two statements you can to 2 things:

1. add `using timestamp` to your queries and set it explicitly on client code - this will prevent the inconsistencies
2. use batch

Comment: Generally speaking - the order should not matter. If I update field1 and then field2 or field2 and then field1 I want to get the same outcome. So in my mind its not about the order but the eventual consistency. So if 2 different updates to the different fields might fail but one update with 2 field changes will not fail - it would be good to know that.

Comment: In that case to achieve strong consistency you need to check this formula `NUM_WRITES + NUM_READ > REPLICATION_FACTOR` basically you always have to make sure that the number of the nodes that need to respond to a write request and that need to respond to the read request for the fields that you need are greater than the replication factor. Splitting the operations doesn't influence it then other than being slightly slower because of the client side processing.

Comment: but if the reads and writes are quorum, won't that be sufficient? Again these are 2 updates to 2 separate fields.

Comment: In theory yes this should suffice. If both read and write are with quorum it should be fine. Please provide the code that you are actually using to make the updates. Also is the value just set to some "old value" or is it undefined. It might be that you are unintentionally updating some fields. Also if read comes relatively close to the second update (millis level) then also the clock on nodes kicks in. I would need more detail to pin point exact source of trouble, but to be honest it's starting to look like qery ordering problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I would have done,is change the table definition

```
        CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME(
      id text,
      field text,
      value text
    PRIMARY KEY( id , field )
```

This way you don't have to worry about updates to fields for a particular key.

Your queries would be ,

```
        INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (id , field , value  ) VALUES ('key','fieldname1', 'value1' );
    INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (id , field , value  ) VALUES ('key','fieldname2', 'value2' );
```

The drawback of design is, if you have too many data for 'key',it would created wide row.

For select queries -

```
SELECT * from TABLE_NAME where id ='key';
```

On client side, build your object.